# Why aren't my spruce saplings growing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was looking to make a big 2x2 spruce tree in minecraft, and there's plenty of space for it, but it wont grow. I am in Minecraft Version 1.11, and I am very confused.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your setup?

Answer (score 2):

> "must have a light level of at least 8 in the sapling block. A sapling
> will uproot with light level 7 or less in the sapling block itself
> unless it has a view of the sky that is fully unobstructed (except by
> glass or other transparent materials). The sapling must also have at
> least 4 blocks of space above it; the amount of required space varies
> between the different species of trees. If there is a ceiling above a
> sapling, this will limit the maximum height of the tree that can grow
> from that sapling."
>
> "In order to grow a 2×2 tree (be it spruce, jungle or dark oak), four saplings must be placed adjacent to each other in a square. **For growth to succeed, there may be no blocks adjacent (even diagonally) to the north-western sapling** (which is considered the center of the tree) up to the final height of the tree."

According to minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tree

So if you're sure it has enough space, the problem must be the light or a block close to the northwestern sapling. To find the northwestern sapling, use your debug (F3) screen

Answer (score 1):

From the Official Minecraft Wiki

> 2×2 spruce trees require a 5×5 column of unobstructed space
>   at least 14 blocks above the saplings to grow
>   (15 blocks including the saplings themselves).
>   This column is centered on the northwestern sapling.
>   A 3×3 area is required at the base of the tree (the level of the saplings).

See if your setup meets that criteria. If not, you will not get a "giant" spruce to grow.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, only Dark Oak and Jungle Saplings can be 2x2. Could be wrong though, I haven't played MC in forever, but I do follow updates and I don't remember any updates to 2x2-able trees.

Comment: It's been in the game since 1.7.2 according to http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tree#History